# Angular - load version 4 beta to a plunker

Tags: javascript, angular, systemjs, plunker

I have a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=preview) with Angular version 2. In GitHub the master branch is version 4-beta, how can I load the newer version so I can play with things in plunker?

Systemjs config:

```
  map: {

    'app': './src',

    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',

    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.0.2/lib/typescript.js'
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the version like this:

```
map: {
    ...
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core@4.0.0-beta.3/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common@4.0.0-beta.3/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler@4.0.0-beta.3/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser@4.0.0-beta.3/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.0.0-beta.3/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http@4.0.0-beta.3/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router@4.0.0-beta.3/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms@4.0.0-beta.3/bundles/forms.umd.js',
    ...
}
```